# How to find which program is under the cursor?

Tags: linux, gnome

I had an annoying program showing up on my gnome desktop, naming itself with the quite generic name "Back Up". By chance I could find from which program/package it came from but out of curiosity, is there a tool to identify the executable name linked to a window?

Comment: possibility of it being 'MyPC Backup'? - which is a PUP installed with other apps on Win, Mac & nix

Comment: No it was not, and the app itself is just a teaser, I could find it but I care about the general case: identify a crappy desktop application without its name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041532/getting-pid-and-details-for-topmost-window

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137875/tell-a-process-pid-by-its-window